# Dell R710 OS install

Tags: linux, debian

I just bought a couple Dell R710s on Ebay for a home lab and want to install Debian as the main OS.  Im new to dealing with server administration aside from Development stuff.  I am wondering on where to install the OS since there is no internal drive but an internal USB.  Is this the proper way to install the main OS on the USB internally?  Im not planning on doing much with these but have some VMs for dev stuff and maybe camera storage.  Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper approach would be to install a couple of SATA drives using drive caddies, then install the OS using mirroring. VMs and camera images tend to be time consuming to re-create so you don't want a dead hard drive killing your entire environment. You might be able to get hardware mirroring working depending on your specific hardware, but if you can't, software mirroring on Linux is quite reliable.

- Info on Debian with software mirroring: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/SoftwareRaidRoot
- One example of a 3.5" drive caddy: [http://www.amazon.com/Drive-Caddy-Server-SASTu-Replacement/dp/B00524SIQ2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00524SIQ2) [$12]

It is technically possible to install on USB, but not a good idea for performance and reliability reasons.